# Use case of HATEOAS between Angular frontend and Spring Boot

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-hateoas

Will it be a good approach if I use HATEOAS and use API response with proper links to build a dynamic loosely coupled application, where It will not be hard coded URIs in frontend(Angular)(Most of the call). Only use ref, soo even if i change my api URI, frontend will not be impacted.

Haven't tried it yet, but thinking about it conceptually.

Comment: here on stackoverflow are many questions/answers on this topic also i suggest you to watch next one video about it. It is from Spring I O conference from this year [REST next level](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93UK4gwV41c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it is possible. But i think it is not necessary if your application is not changing in next versions completely. If your Angular App stays the same i would not see any real benefit to use HATEOS instead of static URL paths in your Angular Services. If you need your Angular App full dynamic then it is a good apporch to save time for changes later.